# Does Windows Phone 7 have a YouTube player similar to iPhone?

Tags: youtube, windows-phone-7

I want to allow my phone app users to be able to click a YouTube video and be sent to the phone's YouTube player. Does Windows Phone 7 have that option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing has yet been announced but I know someone at Google who was talking with Microsoft about developing a YouTube app for Windows Phone 7.

Even if such an app did exist, based on the sandboxed nature of apps and their inability to launch other apps, your only options is likely to be to open the video in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm quite sure that there will be a Youtube App for Windows Phone. Beside that, since Youtube is going HTML5 anyway, I think it is trivial to include a playback of a Youtube video directly in your app:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769551%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The current version of IE mobile that runs on the Windows Phone 7 device emulator CANNOT play YouTube videos. So far from all the evidence that I've seen, you cannot use the Silverlight "MediaElement" control to play YouTube videos, nor can you use the iPhone "trick" of embedding a YouTube video in a bunch of HTML and have Safari handle it for you because IE mobile won't play YouTube videos.

This isn't to say that they won't be adding this feature in the future, but I'm pretty disappointed that as of Beta 1, it doesn't appear that WP7 has ***any*** YouTube support.